# Best Approach on Social Authentication Providers

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

Currently I am developing an application with several access methods based on Laravel/Socialite, I want to allow users authenticate with facebook, twitter, google so far or creates it's own account by filling a form with name, email, password.

Routes

login/
login/facebook
login/twitter
login/google

Questions :

¿What is the best approach once the User data has been obtained from the auth provider?

¿How to handle a common data user storage?, I mean, I am storing only person name, email and avatar, but  how about the token provided by the auth process.

¿How to handle when user log in with more of 1 providers with a same email address?

And how to handle when a user set  password to his account created trough facebook?

I thank your attention .

Comment: The explanation is probably too long and there are many approaches for this. I suggest you to start by following [these steps](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9) for setting up *socialite*, a Laravel package. I implemented it for [my project](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid) with good results, and a [working demo](http://demo.timegrid.io/)